# How and where can I write ARM Assembly codes in Embarcadero Delphi XE5 with Android?

Tags: delphi, mobile, assembly, arm, llvm

How and where can I write ARM Assembly codes in Embarcadero Delphi XE5 with Android?
That would be the best, if I can write it inline.

Answer (score 7):

Delphi mobile compiler do not support the `asm ... end` blocks.

But the "old good way" is still available, since we are talking about a *Native* compiler.

What you can do is [compile your own module with an external assembler](http://www.coranac.com/tonc/text/asm.htm) (e.g. GNU AS), then link it to your Delphi XE* application.

For instance, `System.RTTI` uses low-level asm tricks via external statically linked files:

```
procedure RawInvoke(CodeAddress: Pointer; ParamBlock: PParamBlock);
  external 'librtlhelper.a' name 'rtti_raw_invoke';

procedure RawIntercept;
  external 'librtlhelper.a' name 'rtti_raw_intercept';
```

Take a look [at this Japanese article](http://blogs.embarcadero.com/teamj/2013/05/16/3888/) - Google translate is your friend!

Comment: How do you know that these external objects are coded in asm. Could equally well be any language and compiled down to native.

Comment: For x86 and x64, `RawInvoke()` and `RawIntercept()` are written in assembly directly in `Rtti.pas` itself. For ARM, it would make sense for Embarcadero to keep it written in assembly and adjust it as needed, rather than translate it to a higher level language. Why do you think the RTL still uses inline assembly in its core routines and never enabled the PUREPASCAL versions of them? Thye are more efficient in assembly.

Comment: @Remy That's a different point. My point is that it's not clear that it's asm. Writing ARM assembler is ery different from x86. So perhaps it was easier to write in C, say.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Try to write such startup code in plain C. It will be much less readable than asm, since you will need to handle each register individually. Take a look at the corresponding x86/x64 versions inlined in rtti.pas. I know a little about what I'm talking about, since I wrote similar low-level code for mORMot.pas - take a look at my own x86/x64 bootstrap code version of RawIntercept, and you will probably find out that I know what I'm talking about, especially in comparison with how RTTI.pas is coded. BTW the OP question was about writing ARM asm.

Comment: I know that the question is about writing asm. I expect that those functions are asm. My point is that they need not be.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan this is not any routine but low level bootstrapping code which needs to handle CPU registers explicitly. Impossible in pascal. A nightmare in c. Easy in asm.I see no reason not to use ask here.

Comment: I already acknowledged that. We are talking at cross purposes.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible.

[`Use Atomic Instrinsics Instead of Assembly Language`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Migrating_Delphi_Code_to_Mobile_from_Desktop#Use_Atomic_Instrinsics_Instead_of_Assembly_Language).

Quote:

> The Delphi mobile compilers do not support a built-in assembler.

Answer (score 1):

The Delphi mobile compilers do not support inline assembler. The [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Using_Inline_Assembly_Code) makes this clear:

> The inline assembler is available on:
>
> - DCC32.EXE, the Delphi Command Line Compiler
> - DCC64.EXE, the Delphi 64-bit Command Line Compiler
> - DCCOSX.EXE, the Delphi Cross Compiler for OS X

You'll need to find an assembler to create something that the Delphi mobile compiler can consume, for instance a shared library.

Answer (score 1):

You can not.

LLVM - which is the engine behind Delphi Mobile - has its kind of an assembler language: http://llvm.org/docs/CommandGuide/llvm-as.html 
But it would hardly be ARM kind or x86 kind, since LLVM tries to be CPU-agnostic.

Anyway Delphi officially has no support neither for CPU-native assembling language nor for LLVM kind of it.

- http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE4/en/Migrating_Delphi_Code_to_iOS_from_Desktop#Use_Atomic_Instrinsics_Instead_of_Assembly_Language
- http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE4/en/Using_Inline_Assembly_Code